# Check array in JS - is list sorted?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to create a program that checks the list in the array is sorted. I have three input data:

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,8,9,9

1,2,2,3,2

So here is my code:

```
let sorts = +gets(); // 3
let list = [];

for (let i = 0; i < sorts; i++) {
    list[i] = gets().split(',').map(Number); // The Array will be: [ [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 1, 2, 8, 9, 9 ], [ 1, 2, 2, 3, 2 ] ]
}

for (let i = 0; i < list[i][i].length; i++){
    if (list[i][i] < list[i][i +1]) {
        print('true');
    } else {
        print('false');
    }
}
```

I need to print for all lists on new line true or false. For this example my output needs to be:

true

true

false

I have no idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
var str = ["1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,8,9,9", "1,2,2,3,2"];

for (var i in str){
    var list = str[i].split(',').map(Number);
    console.log(list);
    var isSorted = true;
    for(var j = 0 ; j < list.length - 1 ; j++){
        if(list[j] > list[j+1]) {
            isSorted = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(isSorted);
}
```

Comment: This is really easy, but did you know how to create my Array like your (str): https://pastebin.com/tBFd9Uft 
Edit: I get it, only need gets() without .split()

Answer (score 32):

You can use [`array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if each value is greater than the previous value.

```js
const isSorted = arr => arr.every((v,i,a) => !i || a[i-1] <= v);
console.log(isSorted([1,2,3,4,5]));
console.log(isSorted([1,2,8,9,9])); 
console.log(isSorted([1,2,2,3,2]));
```

Comment: Make it shorter: `arr.every((v,i,a) => !i || a[i-1] <= v)`

Comment: @VisioN Updated the solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Is it really good practice to use tricks like `!i` for `i<1`? Otherwise, probably the right way to do this.

Comment: @JollyJoker I wouldn't call it a trick--it's equivalent to `i === 0` (which might be more readable). This is the best solution on the thread because it combines early bailout with modern, functional syntax.

Comment: @ggorlen Some things are standard in Javascript that would be considered oddities to avoid in other languages

Answer (score 28):

How about something like this:

```
!![1,2,3,4,5].reduce((n, item) => n !== false && item >= n && item)
// true

!![1,2,8,9,9].reduce((n, item) => n !== false && item >= n && item)
// true 

!![1,2,2,3,2].reduce((n, item) => n !== false && item >= n && item)
// false
```

Reduce will literally reduce the array down to a single value - a boolean in our case.

Here, we are calling a function per iteration, the `(n, item)` is our function signature, it's body being `n !== false && item >- n && item` - we are making sure that `n` exists (n is our accumulator - read up!), testing if `item` is greater than `n`, and making sure `item` exists.

This happens for every element in your array. We then use `!!` to force the result into a tru boolean.

Comment: That's a clever one, though it would be worth to give the user an explanation, unexperienced programmers would never understand what's happening here. For sake of testing, here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/briosheje/46r1jm03/

Comment: Indeed. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` will return `false`.

Comment: @VisioN This is a very good point indeed.

Comment: @Stuart Just change `n &&` to `n !== false &&` in lambda.

Comment: `.reduce((n, item) => n && item >= n && item)` can be refactored into a method

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Correct. That will be an exercise of OP though eh... :)

Comment: Good implementation of using higher-order functions, you have my up-vote!

Comment: Will this short circuit?

Comment: @BobBrinks Nope. It'll keep on chugging along over a list of 1,000,000 elements even if the first two aren't sorted. `arr.every` has my vote.

Comment: `[0, 0]` returns `false`.

Answer (score 13):

> Simply try this way by using  `slice` method : It will check if previous element is less than the next element.If the condition is true for every element then it will return true else false

```
arr.slice(1).every((item, i) => arr[i] <= item);
```

---

Checkout this below sample as Demo

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,8,9,9],[1,2,2,3,2],[0,1,2,3,4,5]];

function isArrayIsSorted (arr) {
  return arr.slice(1).every((item, i) => arr[i] <= item)
}

var result= [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
result.push(isArrayIsSorted(arr[i]))
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

## Sorted Number Lists

### Including Negative Numbers, Zeros, and Adjacent Duplicates

Use [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method which will return true should all of the numbers be in order otherwise it will return false. The conditions are as follows:

```
(num <= arr[idx + 1]) || (idx === arr.length - 1)
```

1. if the current number is less than or equal to the next number...

   **OR...**
2. if the current index is equal to the last index...

   ```
    return 1 (truthy)
   ```

---

### Demo

```js
var arr0 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr1 = [1, 2, 8, 9, 9];
var arr2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 2];
var arr3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 3];
var arr4 = [-3, 0, 1, 3, 3];
var arr5 = [-4, -2, 0, 0, -4];

function sorted(array) {
  return array.every(function(num, idx, arr) {
    return (num <= arr[idx + 1]) || (idx === arr.length - 1) ? 1 : 0;
  });
}

console.log(arr0 +' | '+sorted(arr0));
console.log(arr1 +' | '+sorted(arr1));
console.log(arr2 +' | '+sorted(arr2));
console.log(arr3 +' | '+sorted(arr3));
console.log(arr4 +' | '+sorted(arr4));
console.log(arr5 +' | '+sorted(arr5));
```

Comment: for `[0, 1, 3, 4, 5]` it returns false

Comment: See update, thanks @LucaRainone

Comment: The point is that the trick is dangerous. For example it does not works with negative numbers. `[-2, 0, 3, 4, 5]`. But also your solution does not work for `[0, 0, 1, 4, 5]`

Comment: The callback for `every` gets value, index and the array. Aren't you comparing value to index?

Comment: See update, thanks @LucaRainone

Comment: Good point @JollyJoker so I refactored my answer using the parameters correctly, thanks.

Comment: every() shortcircuits, which is great. also tested this version for empty and unit array.

here is a slightly shorter version:
```function sorted(array) {
  return array.every(function(num, idx, arr) {
    return idx === 0 || arr[idx - 1] <= num
  });
}```

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of ways how to do that. Here is mine

```js
const isArraySorted = array =>
  array
  .slice(0) // clone array
  .sort((a, b) => a - b) // sort it
  .every((el, i) => el === array[i]) // compare with initial value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use this helping method that checks if is sorted correctly:

```js
    var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4];
    var arr2 = [3, 2, 1];

  console.log(checkList(arr1));
  console.log(checkList(arr2));
    
    function checkList(arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i + 1]) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: [1, 0, 1] - true

Answer (score 1):

You can check if *stringified sorted copy of original array has same value as the original one*. Might not be the most cool or performant one, but I like it's simplicity and clarity.

```js
const arraysToCheck = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  [1, 2, 8, 9, 9],
  [1, 2, 2, 3, 2]
]

const isSorted = arraysToCheck.map(
  item => JSON.stringify([...item].sort((a, b) => a - b)) === JSON.stringify(item)
 );


console.log(isSorted);
```

Answer (score -2):

If i get what you mean, you want to know if an array is sorted or not. This is an example of such a solution, try it. I pasted some codes below.

```
var myArray=[1,4,3,6];

if(isSorted(myArray)){

    console.log("List is sorted");
}else{
    console.log("List is not sorted");
}

function isSorted(X){

var sorted=false;

for(var i=0;i<X.length;i++){

        var next=i+1;

    if (next<=X.length-1){

        if(X[i]>X[next]){
            sorted=false;
            break;
        }else{
            sorted=true;

        }
    }

}


return sorted;

}
```