# Looking for sample JavaScript code to verify an Array of Strings (mixed text and numbers) is in ascending (A-->Z) order

Tags: arrays

If I have an array of "abc123, dsic320, sdlkjas403, zdsoi, zzzdisdi1" and I need to have JavaScript confirm if this is array in ascending order - what would a sample JS code look like to perform this evaluation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check array in JS - is list sorted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833139/check-array-in-js-is-list-sorted)