# Using JS every() method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test if an array is sorted in ascending order using the JS every method: checking if every element is smaller than the next index.

I don't understand why my code below is not working.

```
const testArray1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
const testArray2 = [25, 51, 32, 12, 15];

const isAscending = (element, index, array) => {element < array[index + 1]};

console.log(testArray1.every(isAscending));// expecting true, but getting false

console.log(testArray2.every(isAscending));// expecting false, getting false
```

I am aware that the sort method exists, this is for a school exercice.

Comment: What happens when the last number is compared with undefined?

Comment: Do you get an error in the console? Perhaps index+1 results in an IndexOutOfBoundsException for the last element, as there is no last + 1.

Comment: When you are at the last element you try to compare it with the length+1 which is out of bounds. This returns false

Comment: @morsor — JavaScript arrays are dynamic. Undefined values are just `undefined`. Accessing them doesn't raise an exception.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833139/check-array-in-js-is-list-sorted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. [Your arrow function always returns `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions) because it is missing a `return` statement.
2. You are comparing the last value in the array to `undefined` (e.g. when `i` is `5` for the first array, `element` is `6` and `array[5 + 1]` is `undefined`) which is always `false` so you need to implement a special case for that entry.

Comment: Not OP but completely missed the 1st point. My thoughts was on the second 1